# Result null jump to catch block in mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose, error-handling

I need to add new object in mongodb.

step 1 - checking if user already exist

step 2 - if result is empty then then creating new user

**Problem**
I am using try catch syntax so if  user doesn't then it jumping to catch block, because await result is null, so that can we prevent result null is jumping to catch block ?

```
exports.create = async (req, res, next) => {
try {
   // collection 
   user = await User.findOne({ name: name });

   if (user.name) {
     return res.json({ status: 500, message: "already exist"});
   }


   // adding new user 
   let newUser = await User.create({ newUserObject }, { new: true });
   if(newUser) {
    return res.json({ message: "Your account was successfully created! ", status: 200 
    });
   }



} catch(err) {
 res.json({ status: 500, message: err.message || err.toString() });
}
});
```

Comment: If `User.findOne` returns `null`, it's not an error, it's just a result. If you fall in the `catch` block, it means there's a real error. What is it? What's the message? Have you logged it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code doesn't enter catch block because `.findOne()` return null. It's because you called `user.name` when `user` is null. Just change your condition to `user && user.name` then it will work as expected.